# Combining multiple text files

Tags: r, import, purrr, txt

```
library(tidyverse)
(files_to_read <- list.files(path="/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT"))

read_a_file <- function(x){
  read.delim(file = file.path("/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT",x)
         ,header = TRUE) %>% mutate(filename=x) 
}

(myresults<-purrr::map_dfr(files_to_read,
               read_a_file))
```

I have been doing the above command and it has given me the following error:

```
Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$filename` <character> and `..4237$filename` <logical>.
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map_dfr(files_to_read, read_a_file)
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
 5. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)IMprot
```

Comment: Try after making this change inside your function: `mutate(filename=x, across(where(is.logical), as.character)))`

Comment: Remembering that the files are ".txt". Unfortunately the error remains, with your guidelines:

Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$filename` <character> and `..20649$filename` <integer>.
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map_dfr(files_to_read, read_a_file)
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
 5. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
>

Comment: Error in dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id) :

Comment: In that case, change to `mutate(filename=x, across(everything(), as.character)))`. It will change all variables to character format, but you'd have to then convert them to whatever you need them to be for your analysis.